# How to apply css to DOM element having same class name

Tags: html, css

How to apply css to element having same class name.i want apply `css` to both how can I do this?
I try many times but don't get it right way.

```
<div class="a">...</div>
<span class="a">..</span>
```

I am writing my css inside HTML itself inside `<script>` tag

Comment: Your question is not specific enough to give you an answer for this. Do you want to make both elements with the `a` class to have the same styles or different or what do you need? You should extend your question with more details.

Comment: i will sir thank u i am new in SO that's why it is happening :)  @Kovah

Answer (score 3):

try this in your css file

```
.a{

// css that u want to apply
}
```

Comment: let me try kishan i will let you know :)

Comment: if u put css file in same html then write above code inside <script> tag

Comment: @kishanoza the `<script>` tag???????? That's for Javascript (hence the name) - `<style>` is for CSS

Comment: @kishanoza that comment was deleted quickly! :D np, mistakes happen :)

Answer (score 0):

When targeting classes in CSS you must do it as follows:

```css
.a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<a class="a" href="#">This is a link</a>
<div class="a">This is a div</div>
<span class="a">This is a span</span>
```

This will target all elements with this class `a`, as shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.a {
    color: red;
}

span.a {
    color: blue;
}
```

by this you can apply different css to elements having same class.

To apply same CSS to all elements try this.

```
.a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: copy of another's answer :(